# Expect Scripting - Raising Exceptions

Tags: exception, error-handling, tcl, expect

Im trying to learn Expect scripting to run backend process, is there a way to raise and catch an error exception from this language?

Ex. Python

```py
try:
  raise Exception("test")
except Exception, e:
  print e
```

What's the equivalent in expect?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
package require Expect

# raise and catch exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Tcl 8.6 (which the Expect package will load into nicely), the most literal translation of that Python code is:

```
try {
    throw Exception "test"
} trap Exception e {
    puts $e
}
```

Now, the `try` and `throw` commands were added in 8.6 to make this sort of thing easier. Prior to that (all the way from far further back than I can search conveniently) you would instead do something like this:

```
if {[catch {
    error "test"
} e] == 1} {
    puts $e
}
```

Which is easy enough in this case, but rather more error-prone once things get more complex.

Answer (score 1):

In TCL, you can use `catch` to catch an exception:

```
if {[catch { package require Expect } errmsg]} {
    puts "Import failed with message: $errmsg"
} else {
    puts "Import succeeded"
}
```

To throw an exception, use the `return -code error` command. For example:

```
proc double {x} {
    if {![string is integer $x]} {
        return -code error "double expects an int, not '$x'"
    }

    return [expr {$x * 2}]
}

set x 5
puts "x = $x"
puts "2x = [double $x]"

set x "Hello"
puts "x = $x"
if {[catch {puts "2x = [double $x]"} errmsg]} {
    puts "Error: $errmsg"
}
```

Output:

```
x = 5
2x = 10
x = Hello
Error: double expects an int, not 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The</strike> A literal translation of your python example is

```
set status [catch {error "test"} e]
if {$status} {
    puts $e
}
```

This is Tcl 8.5